# Streamlit on macbook

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, streamlit

I need to deploy my keras model as a web application using streamlit. `pip install streamlit` on terminal results into watchdog error which I have failed to fix. I then tried to install streamlit (latest version 0.59.0) direct on Pycharm, I still get watchdog error. So, instead I installed streamlit 0.1 which is the oldest version, installation was succesful. Now I am having attribute errors when I use streamlit's sidebar

> AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'sidebar'

when running `st.sidebar.title("About")

Is this because I am using an older version of streamlit?.

I am using Python 3.6, keras 2.3.1 and tensorflow 1.15.0rc0`

Here is the error when I install streamlit 0.59

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/61/37mkt9tn1mn4862dj16flw200000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/watchdog/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/61/37mkt9tn1mn4862dj16flw200000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/watchdog/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/61/37mkt9tn1mn4862dj16flw200000gn/T/pip-record-ee5z2nr5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m/watchdog Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Whast is this "watchdog error", you should really put all error messages in detail in your question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: Agreed, it would be helpful to understand how the watchdog error is triggered. In general, downgrading to the earliest possible version of any library isn't a recommended fix, there's a reason why new releases come out

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with python version 3.8.2 as mentioned in the below link.

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/283

Follow below steps:

1. Update python to > 3.8.6

   brew upgrade python3
2. Install watchdog separately.

   pip3 install watchdog
3. Install streamlit

   pip3 install streamlit

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to run your streamlit and python in a virtual environment to have less dependency on the pre-installed version of python on your system.

Assuming python3 is installed on your system you can create a virtual env like:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

To activate the virtual env

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

Now within this environment, you can install the version of streamlit and other libraries you need.

Answer (score 0):

Make an virtual environment by using following commands (make sure you have Anaconda Navigator installed):

To create the environment:

```
$ conda create -n sandbox python=3.7.9
```

To run it:

```
$ conda activate sandbox
```

After activating, use this command to install streamlit

```
$ pip install streamlit
```

To close the environment:

```
$ conda deactivate
```